# How to use a map from Leaflet.js inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, leaflet, geolocation

I'm trying to utilize an iframe to have my [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) map's marker to be located at where the user's device is in, with the use of the geolocation API. This is because of this error message `ERROR(1): Geolocation has been disabled in this document by permissions policy.`. I've tried to include the div for the map from Leaflet.js docs on the getting started page; enclosed in my iframe element, with the attribute of `allow="geolocation"`, but that doesn't seem to work, can anyone help with it?

This is the code that is suppose to get the user's location

```
function success(position) {
  var crd = position.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Comment: Did you found solution Danial ?

Answer (score 1):

And wouldn't it be better to use the built-in locate function found in leaflejs?
The error you have may also be because there is a problem with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

```
map
  .locate({
    // https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#locate-options-option
    setView: true,
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
  })
  // if location found show marker and circle
  .on('locationfound', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    // marker
    const marker = L.marker([e.latitude, e.longitude]).bindPopup(
      'Your are here :)'
    );
    // circle
    const circle = L.circle([e.latitude, e.longitude], e.accuracy / 2, {
      weight: 2,
      color: 'red',
      fillColor: 'red',
      fillOpacity: 0.1,
    });
    // add marker
    map.addLayer(marker);
    // add circle
    map.addLayer(circle);
  })
  // if error show alert
  .on('locationerror', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    alert('Location access denied.');
  });
```

Here's a whole [example](https://tomickigrzegorz.github.io/leaflet-examples/#33.location) of working with an iframe.

Comment: The example link is down.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my github account name hence such problems, fixed ;)